# Cannot implicitly convert type 'a.SaveResult' to 'System.Action<a.SaveResult>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a Programm where I use MVC Controllers to call methods from my Services. I now want to call a method via this code

```
[HttpPost("testname")]
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "a_testname")]
public Action<SaveResult> test(int i, List<lDTO> list)
{
    return _Service.test(i, list);
}
```

The method

```
test(int i, List<lDTO> list)
```

just returns a NotImplementedException.

My question is why do i get the error message Cannot implicitly convert type 'a.SaveResult' to 'System.Action<a.SaveResult>' ?

Comment: Do you mean `ActionResult<SaveResult>`? An HTTP request can't return a method.

Comment: `Action<in T>` in namespace `System` is a delegate type. That is what @ScottHannen is saying. You cannot use a "something" as an `Action<>` on "somethings". The inner expression `_Service.test(i, list)` has type `SaveResult` only, not `Action<SaveResult>`. So why do you use `Action<>`?

Comment: That, and a controller responds to an HTTP request. An `Action` represents a method to execute. You can't respond to a request with an method over HTTP.

Comment: I guess that the test() function does return a.SaveResult witch cannot be converted to the expected Action<a.SaveResult>. But as above comments already state, there seems to be a misunderstanding of what you are doing.